# Using javascript to focus on an element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, grails

In my HTML I load a table of unknown elements using a for loop. Each element has a link associated with it and also an textarea. I want a user to be able to click on the link then be redirected to the associated url. This is fine, but I also want the user to be able to long press on the element(which is an image) and be able to edit the textarea, which gets saved once they click away from the textarea.

My problem is as each element of the table has the same id/classname how do I get my javascript to focus just on the right textarea?

My code...

```
 <g:each in="${files}" var="d">         
            <a class = "file" href="${d.uniquelink}" ><image id = "fileIcon"  src="${resource(dir: 'images', file:  'folderimg.png')}" width="100px" height="100px"/>
                <textarea class="captionText" rows="1">${d.name}</textarea>
            </a>   
        </g:each>
```

This loads a html table with different images and different unique links and each images name by default in the textarea. This is fine....

Now I want when a user longholds on the image it puts focus on the texarea of that element so it can be edited.

```
 $('.file').mousedown(function() {
            timeoutId = setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
        }).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
            clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        });
```

This is how I am checking to see if is longpressed.

Then I have tried the following various ways but to no avail, how do I get the textarea associated with the longhold press.

```
 function myFunction(focused){
      //      var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
       //     document.getElementsByClassName(".captionText").focus();
         //   $(".captionText").focus();
        //       .focus();
          //window.alert(focusedElement.tagName);
       }
```

What happens is it focuses on the last textarea in the table, regardless of which one is clicked.

Would it be bad practice to create a unique id for each `<a>` in the table i.e from my database? (See I don't want the user to be able to see unique ids associated with the files)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var timeoutId;
$('.file').mousedown(function() {
   var $link = $(this);
   var $textArea = $('.captionText', $link);
   timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
     doFocus($textArea);
   }, 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});


function doFocus($textArea){
  $textArea.focus();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a class = "file" href="#" ><image id = "fileIcon"  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/file-extensions-1/64/pdfs-64.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
     <textarea class="captionText" rows="1">First Text </textarea>
</a> 

<br/>
<a class = "file" href="#" ><image id = "fileIcon"  src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/file-extensions-1/64/jpgs-64.png" width="100px" height="100px"/>
    <textarea class="captionText" rows="1">Second Text </textarea>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Within a jQuery event handler, `this` is the element the event occured on. That makes traversals to other specific element instances relatively simple.

You could use `next()` based on html shown

```
var timeoutId;
$('.file').mousedown(function() {
  var $textArea = $(this).next();
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    myFunction($textArea);
  }, 1000);
}).bind('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});

function myFunction($textArea){
  $textArea.focus()
}
```

Comment: sorry this doesnt work at all. I have tried altering it to get it working but to no avail

Comment: It doesn't affect thee textarea it does however go into the function

Comment: I don't understand the `timeout`. It means you need to hold mouse down for a full second

Comment: $textArea.focus() doesnt work is what I mean. @charlietfl